# Name change on French passport. Will there be issues coming into the US?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, international-travel

A friend came to the US last year and was harassed at immigration for no reason. It's suspected because of the new administration, and also racial profiling based on his name and skin color.

He is a French citizen and holds a French passport. He recently changed his first name and has a new passport with the name change. Do you know if there will be issues, since during his last visit to the US he had a different name? What shows up in the computer when he comes through immigration? He's concerned he will be turned back or have issues since his last record of entry has a different first name. Do you know what paperwork he should bring to show proof of the name change? Everything he has is written in French. Thank you.

Comment: Was he refused access to the US, or just "harassed" and then let through?

Comment: One might attempt to edit it's ESTA status online and see if the name change raises any flag ?

Comment: @audionuma because the traveler has received a new passport, the traveler will require a new ESTA.  The old ESTA is useless since the old passport to which it is tied will have been cancelled.

Comment: So isn't the first step attempting to obtain a new ESTA ? If the ESTA is confirmed, it at least indicates that the new passport (with it's new name) is considered valid by USA, which answer to the 'proof of the name change' OP's question ?